# Flutter: Is it mandatory to selfSign server to call api in flutter with https

Tags: flutter, api, ssl, https

I have a spring boot server that doesn't have ssl certificate and NOT selfsigned. I want to call certain apis with https://domainName.com/apiPath . (with https:// not http://)
So I found that I can set configs as to accept bad certificates. like this code...

```
import 'dart:io';

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.badCertificateCallback =((X509Certificate cert, String  host, int port) => true);

io.HttpClientRequest request = await client.postUrl(Uri.parse(
    "https://domainname.com/apiPath"));
request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

request.add(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(body)));
io.HttpClientResponse result = await request.close();
```

api call works with http://... But it doesn't work with https://
this is the error.

```
E/flutter ( 8183): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = <domain name>, port = 33028
```

Can I know, for this to work is it mandotory to self sign the backend(server)?
(may be this is a stupid question. I don't know much about this topic)

Comment: did you try using http package and dio package

Comment: I used dart:io. The question is that I want to call an api that is not https(doesn't have ssl or self signed) with https. So request doesn't work. Is it madotory to selfSign or get ssl in backend to call it as https?

Comment: you can http api request which don't require ssl certificate its not madotory

Comment: yeah i can. http works. but I need to call that api as https://